# how do I refresh a childViewControler object when an action occurs on the parent viewControler

Tags: swift, parent-child, ios-charts

I have embedded a child ViewControler into my mainViewControler and it displays a graph.
the main view controller includes an input field and a save button.
I wish to have the graph in the childViewControler reload its data when the save button is taped.
the childViewControler includes a function

```
func refresh() {
        fetchTransactionsAndCalculateTotals()
        generateChartData()
        setChart()}
```

that I would like to call. I have setup a segue from the main controller to the child controller,

```
enum Segues {
        static let toInOutBar = "toInOutBars"
    }

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: UIButton?) {
           if segue.identifier == Segues.toInOutBar {
               let destVC = segue.destination as! InOutBarViewController
            destVC.refresh()
           }
       }
```

I am struggling to get further than this, I have tried to call this function from myUIButton action without success.

Thanks for any support

Comment: Are you connect segue with button to childViewController?

Comment: Hi Omer, The segue connects the containerView in the parent ViewControler and the child ViewControler. I have named the segue in using the identifier attributes panel. I tried to call prepare function in my code as I would any other function. I am not sure I understand what you mean by connect the button to the childViewControler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should link an `IBAction` on the `touchUpInside` action of the button and get your child VC using the `children` property.

```
@IBAction func refreshClicked(_ sender: UIButton) 
{
    guard let vcChild = self.children.first as? InOutBarViewController else { return; }
    vcChild.refresh()
}
```